# Javac multiple classpaths (colon separator not working)

Tags: java, javac

I'm trying to compile a java program that uses multiple .jar files but am experiencing compile problems. I also can't copy the full output from the virtual machine, but i'll try to post the relevant information.

```
javac -g Model.java
```

This ends up getting 33 errors (GL11 cannot find symbol)

```
javac -g -classpath /media/sf_vm_source/java/java_pkg/lwjgl-*/jar/lwjgl.jar Model.java
```

This ends up with 5 errors (GL11 is found) [5 errors are from other jars but i'm trying to get it to work with 2 .jars first]

```
javac -g -classpath /media/sf_vm_source/java/java_pkg/lwjgl-*/jar/lwjgl.jar:/media/sf_vm_source/java/java_pkg/lwjgl-*/jar/lwjgl_util.jar Model.java
```

This ends up with 33 errors again (GL11 cannot find symbol)

Other info:

sf_vm_source is auto-mounted by virtualbox and has 777 permissions recursively including /media.

Moving all the jar files to a local lib file and using wildcards removes the compile error, but of course has its own issues.

Comment: Do you use wildcard because the `lwjgl-*` changes when the volume is mounted (or eventually may change or is not known) or do you have multiple directories with the same starting of name (i.e. `lwjgl-123`, `lwjgl-abc`...) and multiple of them having similar .jar?

Comment: no real reason, may change eventually was a thought that passed through my mind but no other directories within that folder start with lwjgl- so i didn't see any reason to specify the version

Comment: Can you check in the logs (/var/log/messages or /var/log/syslog or equivalent)? I recall having issues in the past that the mounted drive through virtual machines is not stable (I couldn't copy large files). I don't recall my solution, that was long ago :D

Comment: used arch so i could go frugal on ram and disk which supposedly doesn't have syslog enabled by default, though u might be onto something cause when i downloaded the lwjgl library within the VM and put it in home, the errors no longer occur. Also I forgot to mention that I have a symlink from /media/sf_vm_sources to my home directory which may be important?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the relative path in your classpath, then you may have to add the current path(using a dot(`.`)) to all the jars path. Something like this:

```
javac -g -classpath ./media/sf_vm_source/java/java_pkg/lwjgl-*/jar/lwjgl.jar Model.java
```

Also the use of wildcard `lwjgl-*` may not work here

Comment: /media is in root(/) cause sf_vm_source is automounted by virtualbox, also tried switching lwjgl-* to lwjgl-2.9.0 but no difference :(